# Browser scrollbar with added easing - How?

Tags: jquery

How is this easing added to the browser scrollbar. Javascript, Jquery or another script perhaps? Any help/ links would be appreciated.
http://www.moodsofnorway.com/#/home
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://lab.centralscrutinizer.it/the-tiny-scrollings/

That's all that that site is. In a very very simplified way.

Comment: Hello Deus. I'm looking at your example which seems to be a 'scrollTo' function which is not what I am after, sorry. I know the site I linked features this style of navigation, but my question was 'Browser scrollbar with added easing. The horizontal scrollbar in the site demonstrates what I mean. I see jQuery has a .scroll() function, would this function coupled with easing produce this effect? Does anyone know how to implement this effect with code? Thanks

Comment: Then I'd redirect you to http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html. It is a little plugin that should be exactly what your looking for, right?

Comment: Looking at the scrollto demo it doesn't demonstrate any examples like what I have in mind. But I do think scrollto is heading in the right direction. I have been looking at moods of norway script with mozilla firebug and have noticed these functions which I think are responsible for the effect.XDraggedHandler,setNewXTarget, targetXPosition. From working with AS2 Tweens I figure I need to somehow save current position of scroller, then upon scrolling scrollto new current Xposition. This is something I'm going to need a hand with though. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: For an active forum my post is mightily quiet, apart from the input of deus. I'll take pride in knowing that I've stumped all the stackoverflow experts......